# Facebook opens new Activity for login

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, sdk, single-sign-on

in my app is a com.facebook.widget.LoginButton from FB-SDK 3.0.

If I Click on this LoginButton, a new and blank Activity is opened with my dialog authentication. I dont know why this is happening and how i can prevent that. I want the dialog authentication flowing over my normal Activity.
Thanks to the com.facebook.widget.LoginButton i have no code in my Application to Login, everything is done by my LoginButton. Just a onActivityResult-Method which handels the login.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/

Does anybody know an answer? 
Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem...